# IDE for elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, ide

I was searching extensively for having an IDE for elasticsearch. But I am unable to find one. I know it is simple Restclient will do but in most of the rest client the body editor doesnt have automatic indention and all. I was thinking If there is no IDE, I can make one so that other people can also benefit from it. To make it I need how to create an editor? Any tools are available which will do proper json formatting while typing. IF that is there I can start a github project and start making an IDE. I can also add keywords of elastic search and it will easy for developers.

IF that kind of thing is already there please point me to it. I am unable to find out one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The best option I have disovered so far is the Atom plugin [elasticsearch-client](https://github.com/KunihikoKido/atom-elasticsearch-client)

It does a great job in simplifying my ES work. It also has tons of predefined queries like index stats and alike and a neat query benchmarking tool. Be sure to add some helpful JSON plugins like [json-path-finder](https://github.com/KunihikoKido/atom-json-path-finder) and general helpers like [minimap](https://github.com/atom-minimap/minimap) and it gets quite comfortable.

Not as powerful as the combination of `cat/echo`, [httpie](https://github.com/jkbrzt/httpie) and [jq](https://github.com/stedolan/jq) but much more IDE-like.

Comment: Thank you... It looks great..... I requested the developer to release one for VS code as it is built on top of atom. It may not be a big task.

Answer (score 4):

[Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/vscode) has added [an extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ria.elastic).  It currently [doesn't support HTTPS](https://github.com/hsen-dev/vscode-elastic/issues/17), so it's not yet fully ready.  However development is active and I am hopeful that it will become the IDE for Elasticsearch.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at [Sense](https://www.elastic.co/blog/found-sense-a-cool-json-aware-interface-to-elasticsearch). It does what you need.

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the info. But the server is hosted on **found** which doesn't allow ti install kibana plugins.. And the plugin limits the usage to that particular elasticsearch. But what if there is an ide which has multiple tabs and each tab can connect one cluster of elastic search. It wiill be a very good tool for analysis. I hope somebody in the community likes the idea and helps me in atleast starting the project.

Comment: In all honesty, sense is like any other rest client. IMHO it doesn't do a good job to edit your requests and it doesn't do a good job in representing the results. This is most likely also because json isn't a good format for humans to work with. I have gone for a rest client myself, but compared what we have in the SQL world it's years back in term's of working with data.

Answer (score 1):

[DBEaver](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/sql-client-apps-dbeaver.html). Elastic does not endorse, promote or provide support for this application, but works.

Answer (score 0):

**It's worth to try [elasticsearch-head](http://mobz.github.io/elasticsearch-head/)**
*a web front end for browsing and interacting with an Elastic Search cluster.*
It provides information about clusters and indexes.
Also, a chrome [extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/elasticsearch-head) is available.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]